# HashMap Vs Treemap

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I have a code that works if I use a HashMap, but doesn't if I use a TreeMap instead, 
Can anybody tell why Is that ?

This is my code :

```
package ka.fil;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ModelInMemory implements Model {
    private Map<String,BeanRecord> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void putRecord(BeanRecord beanRecord) {
        map.put(beanRecord.getEmail(), beanRecord);

    }

    @Override
    public BeanRecord getRecord(String email) {
        BeanRecord r = map.get(email);
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<BeanRecord> allRecord() {
        return map.values();
    }

    public ModelInMemory() {

    }



}
```

What I mean by not working is that when i use it in a main method I get this :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
 java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source) at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source) 
at ka.fil.ModelInMemory.putRecord(ModelInMemory.java:11)
 at ka.fil.AppBatch.main(AppBatch.java:10)
```

Comment: Could you define not working?

Comment: Can you post the error message you get?

Comment: sorted lexicographically, that is.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei : when i use it in a main method I get this :
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
 at ka.fil.ModelInMemory.putRecord(ModelInMemory.java:11)
 at ka.fil.AppBatch.main(AppBatch.java:10)`

Comment: If you want to know more about TreeMap please cover my [Internal life of TreeMap](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-treemap-in-java.html) tutorial

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One difference is that TreeMaps do not support null keys, but HashMaps do.

With a TreeMap, you would get an exception at runtime if `beanRecord.getEmail()` returned null.

Comment: @Kafil10 So put an if(r==null)system.out.println("this is the answer"); right after the getEmail(). If that triggers, then you will know.

Comment: You are so right, I didn't know TreeMap doesn't support null keys, as I'm pretty new at java . 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are just replacing the line -

```
private Map<String,BeanRecord> map = new HashMap<>();
```

with -

```
private Map<String,BeanRecord> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Then it wont work because you have

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Which does not include TreeMaps. Easy fix for this would be to just do

```
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: +1, eagle-eye! But a wildcard import is a little "too much" imho

Comment: For java.util I generally put a wildcard, just because its so useful and I tend to use it a lot. Otherwise I only put a wild card if I import 3 or more from a package.

Comment: +1 But We are not sure his problem is thisone as wedon't have the error message.

Comment: @Kafil10 then can you please edit your post and add the error message you get so that we can have something more to work with?